# Create my own disk for Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

I need to work on the internals of android, especially create and test new kernel modules, native libraries and native application. Thus I need to create my own android disk image to use on android emulator. I'm looking for the source code for this operation, with all the tools and build programs to have a fully complete image with all standard applications. Does anyone know where I can found this (most of the source distribution are without build files, or dedicated to one platform) ?

Comment: U don't mean the sd card image but the root filesystem, correct?

Comment: Yes, that it, but it is simple as loading the original android source and compile it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [get the source](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) and build it

Comment: Yeah, and that's not very difficult http://linuxclues.blogspot.com/2010/04/building-android-debian-sid.html